# Unix's wwb for Linux?

Tags: linux

I read today about the death of a [great programmer](https://ncwit.org/profile/lorinda-cherry/) who wrote many of the tools we use in Linux, such as `bc`, `dc` and `eqn`; and found out that she also wrote a suite of tools called "Writer's Workbench" or `wwb` which are enumerated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writer%27s_Workbench).

I have been unable to find a port or source code of it anywhere; is it available?

It sounds really interesting.

Comment: The wikipedia article has some information in the "History and Successors" section. That's probably the best you can do.